# How to better translate "et voilá" from french?

Tags: expressions, translation, spelling, exclamatives

In English, there is an expression that sound's like *Ta-Da* or *Ta-Taan* or *Ta-Daaan*

It's is the same meaning as the French expression as *et-voilá*?

- If **yes** how do you correctly spell it?
- If **not** what can be the more appropriate translation in English?

Comment: In what context do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the translation into English is "voila".

It's traditional for a magician, upon completion of a trick, to say, "voila!" Like, the girl gets in the box, he throws the cloth over it or spins it around or whatever, opens the door to reveal the box is empty, and says, "Voila! She's gone". (Maybe modern magicians think this is too cliche, but it's the stereotype.)

People occasionally say this when presenting something that they hope will impress. Like someone at a business meeting might say, "Our design team worked on the new model cell phone for six months, and voila, here it is!"

Comment: hey, yes it is used and understood in English... but is actually a French word!

Comment: Sure. English has borrowed many words from other languages.